# Can't run Grunt from PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, phpstorm

I'm using the latest PhpStorm 9 under Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a small project and I installed grunt. Everything works fine even in a normal terminal, but if I want to run some grunt tasks from the **PhpStorm's terminal** I get the following error:

```
grunt: command not found
```

ps: I know it's not a big thing pressing Alt + Tab to switch to the terminal, but I hate that.

Comment: Your OS? Sounds like it does not see proper PATH environment variable.

Comment: oups! question updated!

Comment: 1) I'm not a Linux user .. but what `which grunt` (or maybe it's `where grunt`?) command shows if run in both external and built-in terminals? Same for `PATH` environment variables. 2) Will it work correctly if you launch PhpStorm from OS terminal and not launch bar/by clicking on app icon?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make here -- PhpStorm (or maybe just built-in terminal) does not see all environment variables as they are if command would be executed in "ordinary" terminal. When launching PhpStorm app from GUI not all environment variables that are normally available in ordinary terminal are inherited by PhpStorm (and hence the built-in terminal)

Comment: From [here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5513463#5513463): "If WebStorm is launched from Desktop (not from Terminal), WebStorm sees incorrect PATH value and fails to load Grunt tasks. If you're using bash as shell, workaround could be the the following: edit your WebStorm launcher and set command to "/bin/bash -l -c "/path/to/webstorm.sh". This command will perform bash login (i.e. reading your .bashrc/.bash_profile files) and after that will run webstorm.sh." -- see if doing the same with PhpStorm will help you here.

Comment: I used grunt (and other node packages like PhoneGap) from PhpStorm terminal and everything worked fine. I don't changed nothing and suddenly isn't working. 

Ps.: if I start PhpStorm from terminal using the **pstorm** or **./phpstorm.sh** command it's the same thing.

Comment: see the first comment: please run 'where grunt' or 'which grunt' in PHPStorm terminal - what is the result? Result of 'echo $PATH' executed in built-in terminal would be also helpful

Comment: result of **which grunt**: `/home/mrbig/.npm-packages/bin/grunt`


result of **echo $PATH**: 

`/home/mrbig/.npm-packages/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
`